# Rewriting strange urls back to website root

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Google has indexed some strange urls and now i'm getting some hits to them.
I wanna get rid off those hits and rewrite them to the frontpage, but seems that I'm lacking some skills to do that.

In this rule im trying to rewrite www.website.com/?f= to www.website.com,
but it does not do anything

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?f=$ "http://www.website.com/" [R=301,L]
```

In this case im getting www.website.com/.html hits and trying to rewrite 
those to www.website.com root, but without affecting www.website.com/news.html

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.html [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.website.com [R=301,L]
```

--bp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that RewriteRule doesn't match query strings. Have your rule like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^f= [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.website.com/ [R=302,L]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.